# Bake displacement to alpha channel

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

I'm trying to make efficient use of texture maps in my code and it would be ideal to bake the displacement of my mesh to the alpha channel of a normalmap. Is this possible (with the BI engine)? Is this a nodes thing? I've not used them before - a good ref or detailed answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could request that Dalai Felinto build this into the Cycles Bake code that he is putting together.  It's a really good idea. Here's his location on the BlenderArtists forum.  I believe that his intention is to completely rebuild all of the baking system for Blender Internal as well.  http://blenderartists.org/forum/member.php?12684-dfelinto

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a post process in the composite nodes, after all the baking is done, with a Separate and then a Combine RGB nodes.